# Processos PHP nunca fecham

Tags: php, c#, codeigniter, windows-service

Olá,

Estou tendo um problema relacionado a um sistema PHP que está sendo executado através de um Windows Service.

**A aplicação funciona da seguinte maneira:**

1. Tenho uma pasta com diversos arquivos e scripts PHP que servem como uma aplicação offline, que roda sempre no localhost, se conecta no banco de dados, realiza algumas funções específicas e depois acaba seu trabalho.
2. Existe um serviço no windows (feito em C#) que está encarregado de rodar essa tarefa a cada X minutos (um tempo parametrizável através de um arquivo de configuração)
3. Dado seu tempo, o serviço executa o script PHP que está nas suas configurações e o mesmo realiza as funções com perfeição.

Até ai está tudo certo, meu script funciona, porém andei notando que mesmo após a finalização do script, o processo `PHP.exe*32` e `conhost` da janela de comandos do windows ainda continuam sendo executados no gerenciador de tarefas. E com o tempo esses processos vão empilhando até haver 800 ou mais processos `php.exe` que não estão fazendo absolutamente nada, mas consomem memória.

**Eis o que eu já tentei**

- Já tentei colocar `exit(0)` ou `die()` no final dos scripts para ver se ele matava o processo
- Tentei alterar o meu serviço do windows contemplando o `Process.Kill()` do `System.Diagnostics`
- Tentei alterar os parâmetros de execução do PHP no servidor setando `max-execution-time` para 60s

Nenhuma das opções surtiram efeito, porém eu percebo que isto ocorre em determinados processos, tenho 3 serviços destes, cada um executando um arquivo diferente e, aparentemente, apenas 1 deles apresenta esse problema.

Gostaria de saber qual seria a lógica que o PHP realiza para matar estes processos ou como eu posso forçar o script a matar o seu próprio processo no final da execução para que não haja essas pilhas de processos rodando.

Estou usando o CodeIgniter nos scripts PHP.

Comment: Já tentou usar a tag break; para tentar parar os processos?

Comment: O processo que fica aperto é do iexplore ou o cmd? vc chama o php assim: `php -f arquivo.php` ?

Comment: O comando `taskkill /PID numero` não resolve? Ou você quer um meio de entender o motivo da execução contínua para evitar que ocorra futuramente?

Comment: @Gonçalo Nunca utilizei esta tag, poderia me enviar um exemplo?

Comment: @rray Não, estou utilizando o comando normalmente `php arquvo.php params`

Comment: @DanielOmine O problema, Daniel, é que esta aplicação é mais ou menos autonoma, eu instalo ela em um endpoint e ela fica lá rodando sozinha, não posso rodar o taskkill no PID, porque ai seria uma outra lógica para apenas fechar os processos em aberto...

Comment: Suspeitei que fosse isso. Um modo de evitar esse transtorno é ter um controle dos processos. No php.net há exemplos nas páginas do php-posix. Apesar do Posix ser linux only, há exemplos de usuários sobre controle de pid sob ambiente Windows. Claro que são exemplos genéricos, alguns com bugs, defasados, etc. Mas já é um caminho para entender o que fazer. Você encontrará também a função getmypid(). Pode ser útil se conseguir controlar o processo. Apenas esteja ciente do aviso na documentação http://php.net/getmypid

Comment: @DanielOmine Consegui realizar o kill do processo PHP através [deste link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686358/how-to-kill-a-running-php-script-in-windows), porém notei que mesmo matando o processo do PHP, o processo `cmd` se mantém aberto

Comment: Acho que parte do problema pode ser a forma como o programa em C# cria o processo.

Comment: @DanielOmine O problema é que depois da execução do processo CMD pelo C# eu imaginei que ele estivesse mantendo aberto, então adicionei um process.kill() e não está fechando mesmo assim.